# saving plt subplot in google drive

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am running my code on Google Colab which I have uploaded my files on my google drive. For more information, I connect to my google drive by:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

I have a piece of code for showing some figs for any epochs. It shows figs well. I have write it as:

```
img_plt=imgs.cpu().numpy()
true_masks_plt=true_masks.detach().cpu().numpy()  
masks_pred_plt=masks_pred.detach().cpu().numpy()  
input=np.squeeze(np.moveaxis(img_plt,1,-1))
gt=np.squeeze(np.moveaxis(true_masks_plt,1,-1))
pd=np.squeeze(np.moveaxis(masks_pred_plt,1,-1))
_,figs=plt.subplots(1,3,figsize=[15,5])
figs[0].imshow(input[0])
figs[1].imshow(pd[0])
figs[2].imshow(gt[0])

figs[0].set_title(f'input image ')
figs[1].set_title(f'mask prediction')
figs[2].set_title(f'true mask')
plt.show()
```

Now, I would like to save these three images on my google drive. How should I do that?

Comment: Hope this resource would clarify   https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=p2E4EKhCWEC5

Comment: Does it matter if you store them as **3 separate files** or as **one file** that contains all 3 subplots?

Comment: @MikeXydas no matter if we store them as separate files or as subplots.

Answer (score 1):

**Before** `plt.show` add:

`plt.savefig("gdrive/MyDrive/name_of_plot.png")`

This will store your plot as a png in the root directory of your Google Drive.

---

If you want you can specify another directory like:

`plt.savefig("gdrive/MyDrive/path/to/dir/name_of_plot.png")`